# Custom method not found when extending Sonata's PageAdmin

Tags: php, symfony, inheritance, sonata

We have used Easy Extends to extend Sonata's Page Admin. So I now have a class that looks like this:

```
class PageAdmin extends BasePageAdmin
{
    public function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
    {
        parent::configureRoutes($collection);

        $collection->add( 'send_page_emails', '/admin/send-page-emails');
    }
    ...
}
```

... and my custom `PageAdminController` class includes the following function:

```
protected function sendPageEmailsAction()
{
    die('Here I am!');
}
```

The problem comes when I try to redirect to my new action. I get the following:

> Call to undefined method
>   Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController::sendPageEmailsAction

**How can I get the application to look in the correct place for my action?**

===

Edit: Here are the relevant parts of `admin.yml`.

```
sonata.page.admin.page:
    class: Application\Sonata\PageBundle\Admin\PageAdmin
    arguments: [~, '%sonata.page.admin.page.entity%', SonataPageBundle:PageAdmin]
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: admin, label: Seiten }
    calls:
        - [ addChild, ['@sonata.page.admin.block']]
        - [ addChild, ['@sonata.page.admin.snapshot']]
        - [ setPageManager, ['@sonata.page.manager.page']]
        - [ setCacheManager, ['@sonata.cache.manager']]
        - [ setSiteManager, ['@sonata.page.manager.site']]
        - [ setTranslationDomain, ['SonataPageBundle']]
        - [ setTemplate, ['edit', 'ApplicationSonataPageBundle:PageAdmin:edit_duplicate.html.twig']]
        - [ setTemplate, ['tree', 'SonataPageBundle:PageAdmin:tree.html.twig']]
        - [ setTemplate, ['compose', 'ApplicationSonataPageBundle:PageAdmin:compose.html.twig']]
        - [ setTemplate, ['create', 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:edit.html.twig']]
        - [ setTemplate, ['select_site', 'SonataPageBundle:PageAdmin:select_site.html.twig']]
        - [ setTemplate, ['list', 'SonataPageBundle:PageAdmin:list.html.twig']]
        - [ setTemplate, ['compose_container_show', 'SonataPageBundle:PageAdmin:compose_container_show.html.twig']]
```

Comment: Did you follow the instruction on https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/cookbook/recipe_custom_action.html to create a custom action? The third argument of your admin service should be your PageAdminController. The error you have could be that you left the default CRUDController of Sonata

Comment: Thanks. I just added admin.yml contents to the question after reading your comment. It looks at a glance like the correct controller is being used.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but did you clear your cache ?

Comment: I've also noticed that your sendPageEmailsAction is protected, it should be public I think

Comment: Cache was cleared -- it ended up being the protected function. Making it public fixed this. If you create an answer highlighting that change, I'll be happy to mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the admin controller action method should be public and not protected, otherwise Sonata will not be able to find the method for your action :

```php
<?php

namespace Application\Sonata\PageBundle\Controller;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController;

class PageAdminController extends CRUDController
{
   public function sendPageEmailsAction()
   {
       // your code here
   }
}
```